# Extrair dados de JSON dentro de JSON que veem de um Web Service servindo um APP Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, gson

Boa noite galera, como vai?
Estou desenvolvendo um APP Android e o mesmo consome dados de um webservice, porém estou com problemas em trazer algumas informações para o APP.

Este é o JSON que eu retorno para o meu APP:

```
{
    "cod":1
    ,"dados":
        {
            "key":"123",
            "time":"123"
        }
    ,"msg":"ola"
}
```

Como vocês podem observar tem um JSON principal e dentro dele tem outro JSON no índice `dados` as informações de `cod` e `msg` eu estou conseguindo recuperar normalmente porém o JSON filho (`dados`) não estou conseguindo recuperar. lembrando que eu estou usando o **Retrofit 2** e **JAVA** (sem nenhum framework no caso) para fazer a comunicação com o webservice. Vocês podem me dar uma luz? Pois não faço ideia do que fazer. Segue classes:

DatasWebService.java

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

import org.json.JSONObject;

public class DatasWebService {

    @SerializedName("cod")
    private int cod;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    private String msg;

    @SerializedName("dados")
    private JSONObject dados;

    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    public void setCod(int cod) {
        this.cod = cod;
    }

    public String getMsg() {
        return msg;
    }

    public void setMsg(String msg) {
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    public JSONObject getDados() {
        return dados;
    }

    public void setDados(JSONObject dados) {
        this.dados = dados;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DatasWebService{" +
                "cod=" + cod +
                ", msg='" + msg + '\'' +
                ", dados=" + dados +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Dados.java:

```
final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                  .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                  .build();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit
        .Builder()
        .baseUrl(Helper.URLAPI)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();

DadosDao dDao = new DadosDao(context);

try {

    // VARIÁVEL CRIADA EM OUTRA PARTE DO ARQUIVO, NÃO TEM PROBLEMA COM ELA
    dados.put("key", dDao.getKey());

    WebService cadWebService = retrofit.create(WebService.class);

    Call<DatasWebService> call = cadWebService.datasWebService(acao, dados);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<DatasWebService>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<DatasWebService> call, Response<DatasWebService> response) {
            DatasWebService datasWebService = response.body();

            if ((datasWebService != null) && (datasWebService.getCodStatus() == 1)) {

                try {
                    // AQUI ESTA O PROBLEMA, ELE RETORNA VAZIO MESMO O WEBSERVICE ENVIANDO O JSON, TENHO CERTEZA QUE O JSON É RETORNADO POIS COLOQUEI PRA ESCREVER NO LOG DO WEBSERVICE
                    Log.i("log", datasWebService.getDados().getString("key")); 
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            } else {
                // FAZER TRATAMENTO DE RETORNO
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<DatasWebService> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });


} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

WebService.java **NÃO É O SERVIDOR! É UMA INTERFACE DO APP**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;

import io.domain.requests.DatasWebService;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;

public interface WebService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php")
    Call<DatasWebService> datasWebService(@Field("acao") String acao, @Field("dados") JSONObject dados);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente criar uma classe chamada Dados com os atibutos que necessita recuperar e depois substitua o atributo JSONObject dados por ela.

```
public class Dados {
    public String key;
    public String time;
    // criar getter e setters
 }


public class DatasWebService {

    @SerializedName("cod")
    private int cod;

    @SerializedName("msg")
    private String msg;

    @SerializedName("dados")
    private Dados dados;

    // criar getter e setters
}
```

Comment: Boa ideia, vou fazer o teste, mas você não conhece outro método que consiga recuperar todos os valores, sem ter que definir antes o que será retornado? Pois queria fazer de uma forma genérica para não ter que definir no APP cada informação que o webservice vai retornar, pouparia trabalho e o código ficaria mais clean.

Comment: De forma genérica talvez consiga utilizando JSONObject, mais talvez seja mais trabalhoso fazer a implementação.

Comment: Certo e você conhece algum meio? Pois não consegui fazer e estou pesquisando desde ontem de manhã e não achei nada na web que se encaixe.

Comment: Pode transformar seu json em um LinkedHashMap e depois acessar os dados através da key. Só acho que essa não seja uma solução muito elegante.

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
LinkedHashMap<String, Object> object = new LinkedHashMap<>();
object = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>(){});

Comment: Certo estarei verificando as duas opções darei novidades após isso... Obrigado enquanto isso.

Comment: Fazendo essa nova classe deu certo, não é da forma que eu gostaria, mas por enquanto esta bom. Obrigado.